# INSERT IGNORE with mariadb using executemany() in python doesn't ignore invalid parameter

Tags: python, mariadb

I'm putting some data from a pandas dataframe into a mariadb database. From my reading of the documentation, when an INSERT IGNORE query hits some bad data (or any other error), it should just drop that insert and continue, but I get this:

```
<ipython-xxx> in xx(table_name, cursor, yy, zz)  
     39     #print(query_list)  
     40     query = f"insert ignore into {table_name} values (?, ?, ?, ?)"  
---> 41     cursor.executemany(query, query_list)  
     42    
     43   

DataError: Invalid parameter type at row 2, column 4
```

Why am I getting any errors at all? Did I misunderstand the docs somehow? Shouldn't it just drop that insert attempt and go to the following one?

Comment: Have you tried using the MariaDB Connector/Python? https://mariadb.com/docs/clients/connector-python/

Comment: @RobertHedgpeth I am using that package for all of my mariadb python code actually.